# Where is the Rule component_rules_payment_component_delete_all defined?

Tags: rules, commerce

In Commerce Kickstart 2. Can't seem to find this code.

Comment: Have you searched the codebase for this string?

Comment: Yes. I assume it was included with the some Kickstart or Commerce Feature someplace, but I can't find it.

What I'm -really- trying to find is a reliable way to delete payments from an order if the user cancels their order. Astoundingly, the Payment Method -adds- a payment transaction, but has no 'undo' that I can see. I was hoping that this rule would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to 'do' -anything-.